# If the product of two holomorphic functions is identically zero, then one of the functions is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to answer the following question:

> If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on some domain $\Omega$ and $f(z)g(z)=0$ for every $z\in \Omega$, then $f(z)=0$ or $g(z)=0$ for every $z\in\Omega$.

Is this correct:
Let's assume that $f$ is not identically $0$ on the domain. Then there is a point $z_0\in\Omega$ such that $f(z_0)\neq0$. Since $f$ is continuous we find a neighbourhood of $z_0$ on which $f$ is free of zeros, $U$ say (why can I say this?) But since $fg=0$ we have $g=0$ on $U$. From the identity principle we can conclude $g=0$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: How can I show that this isn't true if the domain isn't connected?

Comment: Let $f$ vanish on one component, and $g$ on the other(s).

Comment: Regarding “why can I say this”: If $f$ is continuous, then $\{z\colon f(z)\ne0\}=f^{-1}[\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}]$ is open.

Comment: What do you mean by that? @DanielFischer

Comment: If you have $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$ with $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2 = \varnothing$ and $\Omega_i$ open and nonempty, let $f(z) = 1$ if $z\in \Omega_1$, and $f(z) = 0$ if $z\in\Omega_2$. Let $g = 1-f$. Then $f\cdot g \equiv 0$, but neither $f$ nor $g$ vanishes identically.

Comment: Can somebody explain why there is a neighbourhood of $z_0$ which is free of zeros? I don't understand it yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Put $\epsilon=\frac12|f(z_0)|.$

Everything else looks fine.